# Having some issues simplifying an air resistance expression

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, kinematics

I'm having a really hard time with this problem. I tried expanding it and finding the limit as t goes to 0, but I don't think I'm taking the right approach here.. also I have no idea where to go with parts b and c. It reads as follows:

The effect of air resistance is to slow down a moving object. It can be shown that at time $t$, the height $y$ of a falling object initially at $y_0$ is given by the following:

$$y = y_0 - [t + (e^{-bt} - 1) / b] g / b$$

a) Show that for short times this reduces to the expected expression $y = y_0 - \frac12 gt^2$.

b) Find the velocity and plot it as a function of time. What is the maximum velocity?

c) Find the acceleration and plot it as a function of time.

Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the difficulty with parts (b) and (c)? You surely know how to find $\dot y$ and $\ddot y$ from $y(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the expression for small $t$ is the correct approach, but it's easy to "give up too soon"... you need a second order expansion of the exponent as the first order terms cancel:

$$t + \frac{e^{-bt}-1}{b}) =\\
t + \frac{1-bt+\frac12 (bt)^2 - ... - 1}{b} =\\
t + \frac{(1-1)}{b} -\frac{bt}{b} + \frac{b^2t^2}{2b} =\\
\frac12 bt^2$$

The velocity is the derivative of position with time - so that's a pretty straightforward thing to do.

The maximum velocity is reached when the derivative of velocity (the acceleration) is zero; unless you find that the velocity approaches a value asymptotically (examine that derivative - which do you think it is?)

The acceleration is the derivative of velocity.

Can you take it from here?